# Laravel returning blank view for big scripts

Tags: php, laravel

My laravel installation works fine most of the time. But when I need to compute a large amount of data, laravel returns a blank view after 60sec instead of a HTML view.

I have in my code:

```
set_time_limit(0)
```

Moreover, using Log::info('debug'), I can see the script is still executed even if laravel has returned a blank page.

So I guess Laravel has some timeout to return a view before 60 seconds, even if the script is still running.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: It's always possible that your webserver has a timeout limit; most do!

Comment: But my script is still executed despite the timeout, because I output some information in my log files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with mark baker, that must be a server timeout issue.

My suggestion is to use queue for such a big task.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to our load balancer which timed out after 60 seconds. Increasing the timeout limit has solved the issue.